# Using a JTextField to get a regular expression from a user. How do I make it see \t as a tab instead of a \ followed by a t

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtextfield

```
JTextField reSource; //contains the regex expression the user wants to search for
String re=reSource.getText();
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(re,myflags); //myflags defined elsewhere in code
Matcher m=p.matcher(src); //src is the text to search and comes from a JTextArea
while (m.find()==true) {
```

- If the user enters `\t` it finds `\t` not tab.
- If the user enters `\\\t` it finds `\\\t` not tab.
- If the user enters `[\t]` or `[\\\t]` it finds `t` not tab.

I want it such that if the user enters `\t` it finds tab.  Of course it also needs to work with `\n`, `\r` etc...

If `re="\t";` is used instead of `re=reSource.getText();` with `\t` in the `JTextField` then it finds tabs.  How do I get it to work with the contents of the `JTextField`?

Comment: Please learn how to use the code tags/formatting!  BTW - (now I can actually read the code) the `==true` is redundant.

Comment: At what point did you try `\\t`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson the three slashes with a t was showing as two slashes with a t in my post before the edit.  The two slashes is what I tried not the three.  I know the ==true is redundant.  I usually put it there anyway since it reads better.

Comment: do System.out.println(reSource.getText());

Comment: @kornero I did that and it printed exactly what was typed into the JTextField instead of what it represented \t instead of tab.

Comment: @Kevin, when it prints `\t` that is ok, since the user didn't enter a tab but `\t`. Try `System.out.println("|" + reSource.getText() + "|");` and see if there's any additional whitespace.

Comment: There is not: System.out.println("\""+reSource.getText()+"\""); produces "\t"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
String src = "This\tis\ta\ttest";
System.out.println("src=\"" + src + '"'); // --> prints "This is a test"
String re="\\t";
System.out.println("re=\"" + re + '"'); // --> prints "\t" - as when you use reSource.getText();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
Matcher m = p.matcher(src);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println('"' + m.group() + '"');
}
```

Output:

```
src="This   is  a   test"
re="\t"
"   "
"   "
"   "
```

Try this:

```
re=re.replace("\\t", "\t");
OR
re=re.replace("\\t", "\\\\t");
```

I think the problem is in understanding that when you type:

```
String str = "\t";
```

Then it is actualy same as:

```
String str = "   ";
```

But if you type:

```
String str = "\\t";
```

Then the **System.out.print(str)** will be **"\t"**.

Comment: Both failed to make a difference.

Comment: src is simply "This    is    a    test" with tabs instead of spaces and without the quotes.

Comment: @Kevin Can you please run my example?

Comment: I found the problem.  The code I posted came from my regex.java file.  I must have been using an older version of its compiled class that had a logic error.  Once I recompiled it and put the freshly compiled regex.class file in with my program it works perfectly. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Matching `\t` should work, however, your flags might have a problem.

Here's what works for me:

```
String src = "A\tBC\tD";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\w\\t\\w"); //simulates the user entering \w\t\w
Matcher m=p.matcher(src);
while (m.find()) 
{
  System.out.println("Match: \"" + m.group(0) + "\"");
}
```

Output is:

```
Match: "A   B"
Match: "C   D"
```

Comment: by default my flags are Pattern.UNIX_LINES, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE, Pattern.MULTILINE. They can be changed by the user.

Comment: @Kevin those flags work for me, I don't see any problem here.

Comment: If I set the variable re to a string it works it fails when I set re to reSource.getText() even though the JTextField named reSource contains the same value as the string that works

Comment: @Kevin did you check the text returned by the textfield? Maybe there's something else in there. Please post what is returned by the textfield if the user enters `\t` only.

Comment: System.out.println("\""+reSource.getText()+"\""); produces "\t"

Comment: @Kevin, well as I said, that should work. Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://ww.sscce.org)?

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that Java Swing JTextField and JTable GUI controls escape user-entered backslashes by prefixing a backslash.

User types two-character sequence "backslash t", control's getText() method returns a String containing the three-character sequence "backslash backslash t".  The SO formatter does its own thing with backslashes in text so here it is as code:

```
  Single backslash: input is 2 char sequence \t and return value is 3 char \\t
```

For three-character input sequence "backsl backsl t", getText() returns the five-character sequence "backsl backsl backsl backsl t".  As code:

```
  Double backslash: input is 3 char sequence \\t and return value is 5 char \\\\t
```

This basically prevents the backslash from modifying the t to yield a character sequence that becomes a tab when interpreted by something like System.out.println.

Conveniently, and surprisingly to me, the regex processor accepts it *either way*.  A two-character sequence "\t" matches a tab character, as does a three-character sequence "\\t".  Please see demo code below.  The system.out calls demonstrate which sequences and patterns, have tabs, and in JDK 1.7 *both* matches yield true.

```
package my.text;

/**
 * Demonstrate use of tab character in regexes
 */
public class RegexForSo {
public static void main(String [] argv) {
    final String sequenceTab="x\ty\tz";
    final String patternBsTab = "x\t.*";
    final String patternBsBsTab = "x\\t.*";
    System.out.println("sequence is >" + sequenceTab + "<");
    System.out.println("pattern BsTab is >" + patternBsTab + "<");
    System.out.println("pattern BsBsTab is >" + patternBsBsTab + "<");
    System.out.println("matched BsTab = " + sequenceTab.matches(patternBsTab));
    System.out.println("matched BsBsTab = " + sequenceTab.matches(patternBsBsTab));     
  }
}
```

Output on my JDK1.7 system is below, tabs in output might not survive SO formatter :)

```
sequence is >x  y   z<
pattern BsTab is >x .*<
pattern BsBsTab is >x\t.*<
matched BsTab = true
matched BsBsTab = true
```

HTH